# Flutter: How to Bottom Center a Button in a ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to bottom center a button that is contained within a `ListView`. By bottom, I mean at the bottom of the screen, or if the screen content is longer than the height of the screen, at the end of the content.

I can do this using a `Column` with a `Spacer` widget because the height is defined, however my screen has text input on it. If I use a `Column` instead of a `ListView`, the screen overflows when I'm typing.

How can I either

1. Bottom center a button, or
2. Use a `Column` but prevent the screen from resizing or overflowing when typing; I'd like it to ether be scrollable, or simply have the keyboard cover the screen content while typing.

Basic code example:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: workingWidth,
          child: Center(
            child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
              ScreenHeader("Tell Us a Little About Yourself"),
              TextFormField(
                maxLines: 16,
                controller: bioController,
                autocorrect: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                maxLength: 500,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingH5),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorPrimary)),
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorMuted)),
                  hintText: "Enter your bio here...",
                  hintStyle: textMuted,
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(), //This doesn't work because I am using a ListView instead of a Column
              RoundedButton(
                  buttonText: 'Continue',
                  buttonStyle: buttonPrimary,
                  onPressed: () {}
            ),
            ],)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap your `Column` into a `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: Yep no luck. Error  - `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a `Column` without yellow/black stripes error when opening the keyboard, you need to wrap it into a `SingleChildScrollView`, but `Spacer` will not work in that case if you do not declare the height of its `RenderFlex` parent.

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get the screen size on its context and set to your `Container`.

At the end you can achieve the desired layout with this:

```dart
return Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  width: workingWidth,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ScreenHeader("Tell Us a Little About Yourself"),
                      TextFormField(
                        maxLines: 16,
                        controller: bioController,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                        maxLength: 500,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingH5),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorPrimary)),
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorMuted)),
                          hintText: "Enter your bio here...",
                          hintStyle: textMuted,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      RoundedButton(
                          buttonText: 'Continue',
                          buttonStyle: buttonPrimary,
                          onPressed: () {}
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! For anyone else - I was using a `BottomNavigationBar`, so when you set the height of the container, remember to take this width into consideration. You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kBottomNavigationBarHeight` where `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` is a constant value found in `constants.dart`